# How can I use a wildcard to include multiple files for using environment variables in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, wildcard, devops, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

I am trying to do a custom install of [openedx](https://github.com/edx/configuration) and I have a bunch of `.yml` files with environment variables in them inside paths that looks like this

```
playbooks/roles/<component-name>/defaults/main.yml
```

Then, while running a playbook that installs all such components, I'm using a command like this

```
ansible-playbook ./openedx_native.yml -e"@roles/<component-name-1>/defaults/main.yml" -e"@roles/<component-name-2>/defaults/main.yml"
```

Now I want to be able to use the main.yml files from all components and there are about 20-25 of them, so I'm looking for a way to include them using a wildcard, something like this

```
ansible-playbook ./openedx_native.yml -e"@roles/*/defaults/main.yml"
```

This, of course, doesn't work and Ansible throws an error like this

> ERROR! the file_name
>   '/var/tmp/configuration/playbooks/roles/*/defaults/main.yml' does not
>   exist, or is not readable

How do I achieve this? Please help!

Comment: you can use `import_tasks: stuff.yaml` in your playbook using `with_items` on var having list of all components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to *find* the files and [include_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html#include-vars-load-variables-from-files-dynamically-within-a-task).

```
  tasks:
    - command: "sh -c 'find {{ playbook_dir }}/roles/*/defaults/main.yml'"
      register: result
    - include_vars:
        file: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
```

Comment: This seems to be the most efficient approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have flexibility to change & re-arrange environment variables and its values in /group/all.yaml  like `environments:
  - { name: ‘development’, profile: 'small' }
  - { name: ‘staging’, profile: ‘medium’ }
  - { name: ‘production’, profile: ‘complex’ }`

And then you can use this variable for any task say for example you want to create folder with environment name

```
    - name: create folders for Environment
  file: 
    path: "{{ target }}/{{ item.name }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
  with_items: "{{ environments }}"
```